# Display most recent x firebase records in table

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

I'm working on a class project and would like to display the last 5 firebase records in a table as a new record is pushed onto the db.  This works correctly when my page loads but as more records are added, the table continues to grow in size until I refresh the page.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
          productDatabase.ref().limitToLast(4).on("child_added", function(childsnapshot){

          //Grabs key from childsnapshot and sets it to variable
          var key = childsnapshot.key;

          //Store everything in variables from the "child" data
          var product = childsnapshot.val().ProductName;
          var datestamp = childsnapshot.val().DateAdded;


        //Uploading the results to the HTML table
        $("#producttable > tbody").prepend("<tr><td>" + product + "</td><td>");
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear the table before each prepend? Does the `child_added` give you `4` records each time a new child is added, or only one record?

Comment: The code below gives my 4 records on page low and keeps adding them to the table.  Its only when I refresh the page do I get back down to 4 records in the table.

Comment: Have you tried to empty / delete all rows on the table before each prepend?